# Internet Explorer isn't treating non-empty ::before and ::after as children elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors, pseudo-element

My span has `visibility: hidden;` applied to it, and it has non-empty `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements that aren't respecting the `visibility: visible;` property in Internet Explorer (all versions) as they should be. What's causing this to happen?

```css
span {
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 50px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
span::before, span::after {
    content:"asdf";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 8px;
    background: black;
    visibility: visible;
}
span::before {
    top: -15px;
}
span::after {
    bottom: -15px;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c8bLb1np/)

According to the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content):

> When their computed content value is not none, these pseudo-elements generate boxes **as if they were immediate children** of their originating element, and can be styled exactly like any normal document-sourced element in the document tree. They inherit any inheritable properties from their originating element; non-inheritable properties take their initial values as usual.

(emphasis mine)

According to [Microsoft's Developer Network (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> As of Microsoft Internet Explorer 5, a child object can be **visible** when its parent is **hidden**.

So is this a bug where IE is failing to treat non-empty pseudo-elements as children, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does indeed appear to be a bug with IE's handling of pseudo-elements and the `visibility` property. Microsoft was able to reproduce it in response to [this issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/3346391/).

It's worth noting that Microsoft Edge does not appear to exhibit this bug.