# How can I make a dropdown mobile menu with animated three lines?

Tags: html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

How can I make a dropdown menu, for example to this animated menu:

*[Animated transform from three lines menu to cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639040/animated-transform-from-three-lines-menu-to-cross)*

I would want something like this HTML content, but with the above animated menu: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_mobile_navbar

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy. You can try to use this code from the link that you gave. I took this for you:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', ".lines-button", function () {
        $('#overlay').show();
        $('.lines-button').addClass('close');
    });
    $(document).on('click', ".lines-button.close", function () {
        $('#overlay').hide();
        $('.lines-button').removeClass('close');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
    background: #000;
}
.lines-button {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 96px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}
.lines-button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.lines-button span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    right: 18px;
    height: 8px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0.57143rem;
}
.lines-button span::before, .lines-button span::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.57143rem;
    content:"";
}
.lines-button span::before {
    top: -15px;
}
.lines-button span::after {
    bottom: -15px;
}
.lines {
    background: none;
}
.lines span {
    -webkit-transition: background 0s 0.3s;
    transition: background 0s 0.3s;
}
.lines span::before, .lines span::after {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}
.lines span::before {
    -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: top, transform;
}
.lines span::after {
    -webkit-transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
    transition-property: bottom, transform;
}
.lines.close {
    background: none;
}
.lines.close span {
    background: none;
}
.lines.close span::before {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.lines.close span::after {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.lines.close span::before, .lines.close span::after {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
.mobile-container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon,.topnav button.icon{
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Simulate a smartphone / tablet -->
    <div class="mobile-container">

    <!-- Top Navigation Menu -->
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Logo</a>
      <div id="myLinks">
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </div>
      <button class="icon lines-button lines" onclick="myFunction()">
          <span></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h3>Vertical Mobile Navbar</h3>
      <p>This example demonstrates how a navigation menu on a mobile/smart phone could look like.</p>
      <p>Click on the hamburger menu (three bars) in the top right corner, to toggle the menu.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- End smartphone / tablet look -->
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, little question yet: how can I delete "logo" a href and leave only three lines ? And how can I do the navbar that way, that navbar goes over the other elements and is not dependent on other elements ? How can I put the links (what goes, when I click three lines) longer farther from the three lines ? Thanks for answers !